# Radio Button Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

I have a radio button like below

```
Apple
<input type="radio" id="one" name="apple" data-price="10" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="two" name="apple" data-price="20" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="appleqty" name="appleqty" value="" />

Mango
<input type="radio" id="three" name="Mango" data-price="30" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="one" name="Mango" data-price="40" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Mangoqty" name="Mangoqty" value="" />

Pine Apple
<input type="radio" id="four" name="Pineapple" data-price="50" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="five" name="Pineapple" data-price="60" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />

Grape
<input type="radio" id="six" name="Grape" data-price="70" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="seven" name="Grape" data-price="80" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />
```

I this i need to create a array like below

```
   array
      0 => 
        array
          'apple' => string 'light' (length=10)
          'price' => string '50' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array
          'Pineapple' => string 'dark' (length=10)
          'price' => string '60' (length=1)
```

**A Kind Note** : `the array key should be the radio button name, the price should be taken from data-price in radio button`  and i need to serilize this array
This should be done using javascript.

Comment: Please, show the code you've got so far and explain where did you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to iterate the `<input>`s. In order to do so:

1. If you know beforehand the element `name`s you'll be looking for (i.e. `apple`, `Mango`, and so on), you can do `document.getElementsByName` on each of those names, as explained in [In JavaScript, how can I get all radio buttons in the page with a given name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682964/851811).
2. If you don't know them (they are dynamic), just wrap them in a `<div>` with a given id and iterate its children, as in [how to loop through some specific child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5165913/851811).

While iterating the radios of a given `name`, inspect the `checked` property of each in order to know which of them is selected, as in [How can i check if a radio button is selected in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423777/851811).

You'll want to build an *associative array* with keys the following key-value pairs, as in [Dynamically creating keys in javascript associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/351495/851811):

1. `<input>`'s `name` and `value` attributes.
2. literal `price` and `data-price` attribute. You'll need to use `getAttribute('data-price')` to get the `data-price` attribute's value.

Example:

```
function createArray() {

    var myArr = new Array();
    myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple');
    myArr[1] = createSubArray('Mango');
    myArr[2] = createSubArray('Pineapple');
    myArr[3] = createSubArray('Grape');
    return myArr;
}


function createSubArray(name) {
    var arr = new Array();
    elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].checked) {
            arr[name] = elems[i].value;
            arr['price'] = elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;
}​
```

You can see this example working in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/).

Comment: There are lots of code examples in the questions in this very same site that the answers links to.

Comment: I've prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/) for you. What didn't you understand about the code?

Comment: you're doing the `alert` after the function `return`.

Comment: there is no value is storing in the array

Comment: Have you tried `alert`ing the values you're looking for? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/3/. Or this http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/4/

Comment: ok thank you this works for me http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/4/ but how i am make this myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple'); in dynimic