# Javascript Object To Array Convertion For Sending To Php

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript dynimic array creator code as below

```
function createArray() {

    var myArr = new Object();
    myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple');
    myArr[1] = createSubArray('Mango');
    myArr[2] = createSubArray('Pineapple');
    myArr[3] = createSubArray('Grape');
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;

}


function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = new Object();
    elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked){
            arr[name] =  elems[i].value;
            arr['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;
   }
```

In this code i need to send the value as an `array` not an `object`.
I have tried changing the `new Object();` to `new Array();` in  `createArray` function but when i `json_decode` i get the result as below

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'apple' => string 'light' (length=5)
      public 'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'Mango' => string 'light' (length=5)
      public 'price' => string '30' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'Pineapple' => string 'light' (length=5)
      public 'price' => string '50' (length=2)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'Grape' => string 'dark' (length=4)
      public 'price' => string '80' (length=2)
```

if i change new Object in createSubArray function i din't get any values..
Kindly check below

[new Object changed to new Array in createArray function](http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/7/)

[new Object changed to new Array in createArray And createSubArray function](http://jsfiddle.net/sC2LC/8/)

How i can change the object into an array ?

Kindly help me in solving this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Setting the second parameter to `true` forces [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to return an associative array instead of a `stdClass`.

Comment: i need to change this createArray function to dynimic

Comment: you can see there is a line like this  `myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple');`  i need to change that line into  dynimc because i may have 10 groups of radio button those radio button is dynimicaly created so i need to change it a dynimic

Comment: @vaahost Well the first thing you'll have to do is get all your radio buttons, look at [`getElementsByTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) for an easy way to do that. Then you just need to iterate through the list of radio buttons, extract their name and add it to your list.

Comment: I am very new to javascript can you show me an example sir pls

Comment: @vaahost You already [asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456432/radio-button-javascript-array) for your `createSubArray`, and you got a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12457065/99456). You just need to do the same for your `createArray` function, the only difference being that you'll need to fill your `elems` array with the radio buttons

Comment: Hmm Any way i would try but if possible can you give me an example .?

Comment: @vaahost Here's a sub optimal solution: `function createArray() { var arr = new Array(); elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); l = 0; for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) { if (elems[i].checked) { name = elems[i].getAttribute("name"); arr[l] = new Array(); arr[l][name] =  elems[i].value; arr[l]['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price'); l++; } } return JSON.stringify(arr); }` It needs work, but you can take it from here...

Comment: Sorry its not working any way i am trying and searching for it

Comment: @vaahost Yes, of course it's not working ;) I can't guess what your HTML is like, I've given you a general solution, you'll need to adapt it to your own code.